# Is it possible to embed all files from a folder?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, embed, flash-builder

I want to embed all xml files of a given folder. For now I'm doing something like this:

```
[Embed(source="../somefolder/file1.xml", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
private var MyClass1:Class;

[Embed(source="../somefolder/file2.xml", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
private var MyClass2:Class;

[Embed(source="../somefolder/file3.xml", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
private var MyClass3:Class;
```

and

```
var file:XML;
var bytes:ByteArray;

switch (fileId) {
    case 1:
        bytes = new MyClass1();
        break;
    case 2:
        bytes = new MyClass2();
        break;
    case 3:
        bytes = new MyClass3();
        break;
}

file = new XML(bytes.readUTFBytes(bytes.length));
```

The list of XML files will grow to 10+ files, so I'm looking for a more elegant and dynamic way to embed those files.

The files should be embedded on compilation, to load them via URLLoader is not an option.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do they have to be embedded; as opposed to loaded at runtime? Why do you need so many different files?

Comment: Does it matter why? I just wanna know if it's possible. :)

Comment: @roberkules To me it sounds like a problem w/ the architecture / approach. But, there are always trade offs for any dev decision so w/o knowing the 'why' I can't say for sure.

Comment: Whether the architecture is good or not isn't part of the question. Straightforward question - is it possible (if yes, how) or not.

Comment: @roberkules Yes, of course it's possible; you already have one solution for loading multiple XML files in your answer.  This isn't n "Is it possible" style question.

Comment: Depends how you look at it. The provided answers are more or less just workarounds. Generating a zip file is different to embed all files from a folder. To modify the source code using ANT is okay for the Continuous Integration server, but for the local workspace where you just wanna hit "Run Debug" in Flash Builder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do something like :

```
[Embed(source="../somefolder/*", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
```

But you could use a Zip file and access to his content. I use often http://nochump.com/blog/archives/15 to do this kaind of things :

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    import nochump.util.zip.ZipEntry;
    import nochump.util.zip.ZipFile;


    public class TestTextfield extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed(source="files.zip", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
        private var zipContent:Class;

        public function TestTextfield()
        {
            var zip : ZipFile = new ZipFile(new zipContent);

            for each(var entry : ZipEntry in zip.entries)
            {
                var entryContent : ByteArray = zip.getInput(entry);

                if(entry.name.indexOf(".xml") != -1)
                {
                    var xmlContent : XML = new XML(entryContent.readUTFBytes(entryContent.bytesAvailable));
                    trace("File " + entry.name +" :\n" + xmlContent);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This exemple will display all XML File content contained in embeded files.zip

Comment: Correct idea i have improved example from deng.fzip to nochump.utils.zip

you can visit my website http://sourceskyboxer.byethost16.com/dengfziptonochumputilszip It is embed zip loading icons

Answer (score 4):

I can only suggest you to write some kind of code generation script. There can be the following options:

- Flex Compiler Extensions (more details [here](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+3+Compiler+Design) or [here](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-18718)). This way you can preprocess your code and embed metadata. The solution can be annotation (metatags) driven.
- Ant script.
- Your own command line script.

Comment: I'm using ANT to build the project. How would a possible solution using ANT look like?

Comment: I don't like Ant personally but I can suggest you to use Ant Contrib's [`Foreach` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html) to iterate over XML files in your directory and get their names. Then I suggest you to use [`ReplaceRegExp` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) to replace your special metatag annotated code with generated lines.

Comment: After seeing this answer and putting some thought to it; I came back to upvote it.  I think the ANT script approach is a really creative solution to the problem.